# Spark parallelization with fortran library

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, gfortran

I have a model written in Fortran (and it can't be modified) that generates a shared library that is composed by two functions:

- load_model : loads all the model settings from text files, allocate arrays, etc..
- run_model : takes model parameters (specific for each simulation) and run the model with the settings specified previously

I've managed to wrap the library in python using gfort2py (https://github.com/rjfarmer/gfort2py) (f2py didn't work) and now I have a Model class in Python that has inside a load and a run function.

The code looks like:

```
class Model():
    def load(self):
        self.model = gfort2py.fFort(lib_name, mod_name)
        self.model.load_model()

    def run(self, parameters):
        return self.model.run_model(parameters)
```

Note that the actual code is a little bit more complex but I don't think it's important to add complexity here.

Now when I run the model in Python without parallelization

```
mod = Model()
mod.load()
mod.run(parameters)
```

everything works fine.

The problem arise when I try to parallelize the code using Spark. The code looks like

```
mod = Model()
mod.load()
sc = SparkContext()
RDD = sc.parallelize(pars, 4)
mod_RDD = RDD.map(mod.run)
res = mod_RDD.collect()
```

When I try to run this I get an

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__code__'
```

Is there a way to modify my code to solve the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this is a Fortran problem, but a python (py spark) problem. Did you search the internet for `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__code__'`  I think this might give some hints.

Comment: It seams it all depend on the Fortran wrap. If I take the same code but replace the call to the shared object with simple dummy assignment (like square the input) it all works..

Comment: Hi I'm the author of gfort2py, There's now a bug report https://github.com/rjfarmer/gfort2py/issues/9 for me to fix things

Comment: Perfect @Rob I can't share with you the fortran code but, in case you need more information, please go ahead and ask

Comment: Can you provide version numbers for pyspark, python and gfort2py?

Comment: Python 3.5.2, gfort2py.__version__ : '1.0.12', spark version 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I have been unable to reproduce the exact error message you got, though i have ran into other issues so things are not so simple. However, one thing that does seem to work is to add the map function to your Model() class:

```
class Model():
    def load(self):
        self.model = gfort2py.fFort(lib_name, mod_name)
        self.model.load_model()

    def run(self, parameters):
        return self.model.run_model(parameters)

    def map(self, RDD):
        return RDD.map(self.run)
```

and then

```
mod = Model()
mod.load()
sc = SparkContext()
RDD = sc.parallelize(pars, 4)
mod_RDD = mod.map(RDD)
res = mod_RDD.collect()
```

See https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html and the section on passing functions.

This was with python 3.6.6, pyspark 2.3.1 and gfort2py with a current unreleased e42b2fb version. If the unreleased gfort2py version works for you then i'll make a new release. Part of the problem is that spark needs the code that runs in map() to be pickable, gort2py e42b2fb makes things partly pickable, but you'll lose any initialization done on the fortran side, in load_model() unless it is repeated in your run() method.